# Ionic IOS Tel keyboard very big (Zoom In)

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

Hi Developing an app using ionic for IOS. Having the passcode functionality here I am accepting the number from user but for IOS the numeric keyboard is opened as zoomed (zoom in).

`<input maxlength="6" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/" placeholder="Enter passcode here." type='tel' required />`

here I attached the screenshot numeric zoomed keyboard.

[image]
How I can adjust its zooming of keyboard. **keyboard displays very big**

Comment: Is it just the keyboard or does everything look zoomed in? What does the statusbar look like? Can you perhaps share a screenshot of the whole screen?

Comment: @Dexter only keyboard is zoomed. this screen shot has taken from ios emulator that why its look like this but on the ios device only keyboard is zoomed.