# Ionic app and keyboard zoomed in / bigger on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, keyboard

I’m trying to reverse engineer how ionic handles `accessibility features` such as zoomed in app and keyboard.

Here’s my problem: we’ve updated the ionic framework not so long ago because of build problems (it’s a legacy app) and I can’t understand why this zoom happened.

[image: Ionic zoomed in app and keyboard]

On the `left` is our Ionic App

On the `right` is Safari

my index.html has a `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">`
and in our config.xml et have `<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="false" />`

I've compared my problem with this issue [Ionic IOS Tel keyboard very big (Zoom In)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43449816) however, my problem is that everything is zoomed in and not just the keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so after hours of searching the web, the solution was to create the app icons and launch images in xCode. and not let Ionic/Cordova handle it.

[image: App Icons and Launch Images]

On the iPhone 5 or 5s, the problem was not present. But on a higher DPI devices like the iPhone 6 or 6s, Ionic/Cordova wasn't able to get the right launch image based on the phone resolution. And yes! Apparently, the launch image will set the "zoom" for the rest of the app if it's not the proper resolution.